# Is Newton Fellowship in UK for early career researchers?

Tags: funding

I am a PhD student (Astronomy) who is going to submit thesis in the next month. I am actively searching for Postdoc opportunities in the UK. I came across Newton Fellowship and I would like to know my chances of getting the fellowship. Is it very competitive? Is their fellowship enough to survive in the UK?

Comment: Do you mean the [Newton International Fellowship](https://royalsociety.org/grants-schemes-awards/grants/newton-international/) jointly run by the Royal Society and British Academy ? The linked webpage says it's closing for good and there will be no more fellowships from the fund unfortunately.